# Angular JS factory understanding - I have an error when loading

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, frameworks, angularjs-factory

// <...loading all JS in one file by the Mincer library...>

```
angular
  .module('firstapp', ['ngRoute', 'ngMaterial', 'ngMdIcons'])
  .factory('MessagesService', ['$scope', '$filter', '$mdToast', '$animate', MessagesService])
  .controller('MenuController', ['$scope', '$filter', '$location', 'MessagesService', MenuController]);
```

MessagesService is a function;
MenuController is a function;

I received a error: MessagesService is not exists.
If i remove MessagesService dependency from MenuController - it works good.

But i need create Message controller, what will add some toast about application, and dont know, how.

Answer (score 0):

> You could never inject `$scope` dependency inside angular `factory`

It should be without `$scope` dependency

```
.factory('MessagesService', ['$filter', '$mdToast', '$animate', MessagesService])
```

Comment: Omg, it works!

scope, what i mean, may be used to templates? if i need collect the messages, i need to use basic object like "items" in my factory functon code?